# Resistor in parallel to circuit is causing VREG to output higher voltage

Tags: voltage-regulator, attiny85

I am building a circuit to convert a 300Hz PWM signal to a 30Hz PWM signal with the same duty cycle. It's a pretty simple circuit:

[image: Frequency converter]

I'm having a weird issue with the R7 resistor though. It's in parallel to the GND_PWM_IN to 12V_IN part of the circuit. I have it there because the system that outputs the 300Hz PWM frequency tests the resistance of the circuit, and if it is shorted or over ~150ohms, throws an error code. In short, it wants the resistance to be about 100 ohms.

When the resistor is put in the circuit, the output voltage as measured on the 5V line of the VREG is actually around 7VDC. When removed, it outputs a perfect 5VDC. I do not understand what is causing this, but it is causing problems for my microcontroller and the rest of the circuit which doesn't like that high voltage.

Any insight into why it would be causing that voltage irregularity, or if there is a better way to fool the impedance sensing circuit without having R7 there, would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What's the PN of your 5 V regulator? A link to a datasheet (edited in to the question) would be even more helpful.

Comment: VREG is http://www.diodes.com/_files/datasheets/AZ1117I.pdf. Thanks!

Comment: What kind of system faults on this narrow range and your pullup ought to be 5V not 12V !!  Poof ATtiny

Comment: See note 4 on page 2 of the datasheet. 10 uF minimum output capacitance is required for your regulator.

Comment: 10uF is only if you intend to use the full current 1.35A, or 300mA ripple and meet the ripple rejection specs,  which is not possible with 12V input and a huge heatsink.  More important is the low ESR ceramic.  if no high mA switched loads even 1~10uF is fine if ceramic.  The bigger C is for bigger step Ic=CdV/dt and low ripple.

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75, I don't have any personal experience with the AZ1117, but that one note and the bullet point "compatible with low ESR ceramic capacitor" on page 1, are the only places in the datasheet where I see output capacitance mentioned at all. I don't see any support in the datasheet for your claim that the requirement depends on the load current.

Comment: Not that this is the cause of the problem OP is having.

Comment: If you can analyze the discrete schematic, you will understand better what I am saying and know how to do load regulation measurements.  Some interesting things just take more experience and not in the datasheet. take it or leave it. His problem was wrong PWM connections and overvoltage on LDO

Answer (score 3, accepted):

R7 is pulling that input line towards 12 volts and, via the ATTINY's input protection diodes, is pulling the 5 volt line up.  A 5 volt linear voltage regulator will pull its output up to 5 volts, but cannot pull the output down if something else trys to pull the output up.

You should probably connect R7 to Ground, rather than +12.  However, not knowing what sort of circuit is feeding GND_PWM_IN, I can't say for sure it that will work - at least it won't continue to risk damaging the ATTINY, and anything else using that 5 volts.

If GND_PWM_IN is a 12 volt signal, you will need a voltage divider or level shifter to reduce the signal to the  5 volt maximum that the ATTINY can tolerate.

Comment: I agree that R7 should be grounded. But do we need R2?

Comment: @Naz. If you ground one end of R7, you are also grounding PB2 whose function we do not know.

Comment: @JackCreasey I assume that PB2 is input for the 300Hz signal. We pull down this pin with R7 to ground. Should not harm?

Comment: @Naz: We really need to know what is driving GND_PWM_IN, and what the voltage levels of that signal are, in order to determine how to correctly connect the signal to the ATTINY, and to provide the correct termination.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear enough, hopefully I can add some:

Comment: GND_PWM_IN, with nothing connected, shows a PWM signal of 0-5VDC on the scope. The 12V_IN is always 12VDC in. They both connect to a solenoid normally, so the GND_PWM_IN is switched between 0-12VDC to control the DC of the solenoid. When the solenoid is connected, the PWM voltage on GND_PWM_IN reads 12VDC instead of 5VDC.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume that you have nothing connected to 'GND_PWM_IN'. When R7 isn't present, PB2 is only connected to 5V through R2. This is a pull-up resistor, pulling it to 5V. That's fine.

You have a problem with R7, in that it is creating a voltage divider between 12V and 5V. PB2 is then seeing approximately 11.75V at it's input. The ADC of your MCU should not be exposed to voltages between 0V-VCC (its operating voltage), which in this case is 5V.

Vreg is being pulled above 5V by the higher voltage at PB2, which may irreparably damage the ATtiny.

Answer (score 0):

The PWM load is wrong.  even 100 Ohms is too low for just 300Hz low current signal to AtTiny.  That is for a high current switch to a battery.  ( good grief  4K7 ought to be fine.  What kind of PWM did you buy?  A motor speed control?)

[image]

The incorrect pullup with 100 ohms will pullup the LDO output to 12V since there are only emitter follower outputs ( source only no sink )  Thus AtTiny is exceeding 6V limit with potential internal thermal damage and junction overstress.

.